# How to implement css classes in form using laravel collective 5.2 . *

Tags: html, css, laravel

Hi I am developing an application and I need to implement css classes to a form using collective laravel "5.2.*".

The code I have for now is this:

```
{!! Form::model($user, array('route' => array('home.user.update', $user->id)), css clases should go here? or what !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When I try to put css class, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class should added like this..

```
 {!! Form::model($home, ['id' => 'form1','method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['HomeController@update',$home->id], 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'files' => 'true']) !!}
```

Comment: I have 

{!! Form::model($home, ['id' => 'form1','method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['HomeController@update',$home->id], 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'files' => 'true']) !!}

and it is working fine